# call phantomjs from jasmine

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to run this test:

```
 it("should not select anything (emptiness) by default", function() {
        // given
        //phantomjs.open("google.com");  // just guessing

        // when
        var text = wordHighlighter.getSelectedText();

        // then
        expect(text).toEqual("");  // nothing is selected (yet)
    });
```

With commented `phantomjs.open("google.com")` the test passes.

The code I'm trying to test is:

```
var getSelectedText = function () {
        var text = "";
        if (window.getSelection) {   // windows suppose to be open
            text = window.getSelection().toString();
        } 
        return text;
    };
```

Seems I have my npm dependecy set up. At least my test is starting by "grunt" command.

My package.json (for example) looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "express": "~4.4.3",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "karma": "~0.12.28",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.7-10",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor" : "~0.1"
  }
}
```

(also I have proper `Gruntfile.js` and `karma.conf.js`)

**UPDATE:** I end up with an Error (if uncomment phantomjs line):

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: phantomjs

(I'm not sure how I can access phantomjs if it comes from npm-packages I depend on)

If I do with:

```
  var webPage = require('webpage');
  var page = webPage.create();
  page.open(...
```

Then:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449220/referenceerror-cant-find-variable-require-at) as possible solution: but I do use `jasmine 2.x`
And [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891998/phantomjs-cant-find-variable-require-when-using-phantomjasmine) suggests me to split my specs.. Still try to figure it out.

**Q:** How to open the window (make use of `phantomjs`) to make the test working with the `window`'open/not undefined ?

Comment: similar (not really answered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891998/phantomjs-cant-find-variable-require-when-using-phantomjasmine

Answer (score 0):

[`phantomjs.open`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) is not a synchronous function.

Once done, it calls the callback you pass as second — or third — argument.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
it("should not select anything (emptiness) by default", function (/* status */) {
    phantomjs.open("google.com", function () {
        var text = wordHighlighter.getSelectedText();

        // then
        expect(text).toEqual("");  // nothing is selected (yet)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I got it.
Seems there is no way to open browser window like I wanted. I've been mixing concepts (phantom-js specific script and jasmine).

So, instead of opening new page, we may inject whatever DOM/piece of page to our `window` (opened for us by `PhantomeJS` conf) with all injected scripts we specified in `karma.conf` and `GruntFile.js`

```
it("should get selection if text in the DOM is selected", function() {
        // given
        var  body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

        // inject text element to the page body and select that text
        var textElement = document.createTextNode("Hello Hello World!");
        textElement.id = "textElementId";
        body.appendChild(textElement);

        selectElementText(textElement); // select element

        // when
        var text = wordHighlighter.getSelectedText();

        // then
        expect(text).toEqual("Hello Hello World!");
```

}

( I got `selectedElementText()` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse) (nice one)  )